# Django 1.0 fetching max value from database

Tags: django, django-models

How can I execute max query in django 1.0 version. I tried from django.db.models import Max but seems that its available only in 1.1 version and gives error with 1.0.

Please suggest.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, it would be `from django.db.models import Max`, but you're right it was introduced in `1.1` and would throw an ImportError anyways.

You could potentially use `extra()`
http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.0/ref/models/querysets/#extra-select-none-where-none-params-none-tables-none-order-by-none-select-params-none

```
Model.objects.extra(select={'max':'MAX(myfield)'})[0].max
```

Or go to SQL:
http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/sql/#executing-custom-sql-directly

```
from django.db import connection

cursor = connection.cursor()
cursor.execute("SELECT MAX(myfield) from myapp_mytable")
max = cursor.fetchone()[0]
```